# In Train Simulator 2015, is there a way to use SI units?

Tags: train-simulator-2015

In Train Simulator 2015 (TS2015), is there a way to use the International System of Units (SI) instead of the Imperial units? This option does not seem available from the menus and options.

Comment: I think it's based on the route you select, but I don't have a computer I can check on right now. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The units used depend on the route you select -- based on what that country actually uses.

For example, routes in Germany should use SI (km) units while those in the UK or USA use Imperial measurements (miles).